# How do I prove that a function has real roots?

Tags: calculus, roots

I want to prove the existence of real roots of a function, not solve the function for the roots. I am aware of discriminant, but that is restricted to quadratic functions. I am aware of the intermediate value theorem, but it can only prove the existence of one and not multiple real roots...

In particular, I am looking to prove that $x^4 - 1102x^3 - 2018 = 0$ has at least $2$ real roots.

Edit: Using the graph, I know the roots are at 1102 and -1.23333. Is using IVT to prove them, using 2 different domains, [1101, 1103] and [-2, -1] a valid proof?

Comment: Can you input the function in the question?

Comment: If function is differentiable sometimes nth order derivative of function comes in handy.

Comment: Graphing the function and observing its roots can give you some direction.

Comment: What do you mean by input? Do you mean if it can be input into a calculator? Or if you want a specific function? If it is the latter I am trying to prove that x^4 - 1102x^3 -2018 has 2 real roots. Also, could I ask you to clarify the nth order derivative?

Comment: Exactly $2$ or at least $2$?  Since $f(0)<0$ but $f$ goes to $\pm \infty$ as $x$ gets large on either side, it is clear that there are at least two real roots.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  If you are interested in a particular function, like the quartic you mention, that should be part of the question.  If you are interested in all possible functions...well, of course that gets very complicated.  There are a lot of functions.

Comment: To add to lulu's comment: The derivative $4x^3-3306x^2$ is coprime to $x^4-1102x^3-2018$, hence we need not deal with roots of higher multiplicity. Therefore, only exactly two or exactly four real roots are possible. But four separate roots would mean that the derivative has three separate roots - whereas the derivative has a double root at $0$ and hence only two seperate roots. Conclusion: Your polynomial has exactly two real roots, both simple

Comment: Try synthetic division by 1102 or -1.22298. If they divide $x^4- 1102x^3-2018$ evenly, you have your roots.

Comment: To clarify,  I am trying to find if theres at least 2 roots, not exactly 2 roots. I will edit to make the quartic function part of my question. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: A nit:  Polynomials of all degrees have discriminants, which give you information about the roots.  The formula for calculating the discriminant for a quartic is pretty complicated, but you can see it here:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialDiscriminant.html

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $$f(x)=x^4 - 1102x^3 - 2018$$ Its derivative
$$f'(x)=4x^3-3306x^2=4x^2\left(x-\frac {1653} 2\right)$$ cancels twice, once at $x=0$ and once at $x=\frac {1653} 2$.
Notice that 
$$f\left(\frac{1653}{2}\right)=-\frac{2488686346715}{16}$$ and the second derivative test
$$f''(x)=12 x^2-6612 x\implies f''\left(\frac{1503}{2}\right)=2732409$$ shows that this is a minimum.

Since moreover, for large negative $x$, the function behaves as $x^4$, then $\cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$f(x)=x^4-1002x^3-2018\implies f(0)=-2018$$

and $$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}f(x) = +\infty$$

then refer to [**IVT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

It is not a proof but a [**graph**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1cnlp7uegm) is always useful to visualize what is going on

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To prove existence of roots of a continuous function, you can exhibit changes of sign.

For instance,

$$f(-10000)>0, f(0)<0, f(10000)>0$$ proves at least two roots.

(Using $\pm\infty$ like gimusi did is also possible.)

Comment: Thanks for the quote!